# Listing files in a directory into array in C using strcpy and strncpy

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct dirent *de;
    char *filesList[258];

    DIR *dr = opendir("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Training-Process-of-YOLO-architecture\\annotations");

    if (dr == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open folder");
        return 0;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(de->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(de->d_name, ".."))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            filesList[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(de->d_name) + 1);
            strcpy(filesList[i], de->d_name); // strncpy add some unnecessary values at the end of some array elements
            i++;
        }
    }
    closedir(dr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", filesList[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

strncpy adds some junk values at the end of some array elements as follows.

```
2077.xml\ProgramΦ_U═≥
2080.xml$G
2083.xmlam FilesΦ_U═≥
2086.xmlll\ModulΦ_U═≥
2089.xmlstem32\WΦ_U═≥
2095.xml\v1.0\MoΦ_U═≥
2098.xml\ProgramΦ_U═≥
```

Here I'm reading xml files and adding them to an array. Above you can see some junk values are coming at the end of the elements. This doesn't happen with strcpy(). Can someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] of the version with strncpy.

Comment: Are you aware of this part "If the first count characters were non-null, dest will **not** contain a **null terminated string**!" of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy ?

Comment: Why 258? Why not add to the list as you find more files? Try to avoid magical constants like that.

Comment: Hint: never use `strncpy` it is __not__ the somewhat safer version of `strcpy`.

Comment: You complain about the wrong behavior of `strncpy` but in the example you presented us that function is not used. show us how you use strncpy, please. @Jabberwocky could you explain your last sentence, please? Why never use it? Consider: `char arr[N]; strncpy(arr, sourceStr,  N-1); arr[N-1]=0;`. It is actually safe.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the usage you show is safe but rather pointless. You will end up with a truncated string which in turn will be problematic later on, not in terms of security, but in terms of program logic.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I get your point. Anyway in a wider design in which the size of an input is known, so that it is actually a sanity check, it perfectly makes sense (especially if this copy is before a parsing that would fail in case of truncation). As always, it is _context_ that  makes something pointless or not. ;)

Comment: `strncpy` is not good for paths, because of possible truncation. You should just allocate memory of size calculated with strlen (like you did) or if you want to for some reason use array on stack, then use `MAX_PATH` (however this one is not good for wchar* winapi functions).

Comment: regarding: `if (!strcmp(de->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(de->d_name, ".."))
        {
        }`  also need to discard symbolic links, sub directories, etc.  Suggest checking the 'file type' and if it is not a 'normal' file the discard it.

Comment: The posted code contains LOTS of memory leaks as the allocated memory pointer are not passed to `free()` before exiting the program.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", filesList[i]);
    }`  there is NO guarantee that the list of 256 entities will all be used, so need to track the number of entries so do not try to print entries that have never been set.  The posted code is missing a check to assure that the array `filesList` is not overflowed,

Comment: There are LOTS of directory entries that NOT about 'normal' files, which you do NOT want to be added to the `filesList`

Comment: Suggest starting with `char *filesList = NULL;` and initialize a `total capacity` for that list to 0. then use `realloc()` and doubling the size of the list each time the list becomes full. be sure to handle the initial conditions of the capacity being 0.  I.E. the size of the list starts at 0, then 1 then 2 then 4 then 8 then 16, etc

Comment: please read the contents of the header file: `dirent.h` as it has the details you need to know for reading a directory entry

Comment: regarding: `filesList[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(de->d_name) + 1);`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful  3) the directory name might not be NULL terminated, so use the contents of the appropriate field in `dirent.h` for the length of the name

Comment: strongly suggest you use `memcpy()` rather than any of the `str*()` functions so the code will only copy the file name and not the contents of the next field also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code needs to pay attention to the fields:

```
/* Length of name without \0 */ size_t d_namlen; 
/* File type */ int d_type;
```

Notice there is a 'name length' field that can be used when copying the directory name.

Notice the file type that can be used to determine if the current file is a 'normal' file or something else.